# NGINX $is_args $args not working with multiple locations

Tags: nginx

I am trying to host two react applications using nginx, everyting works expect query params ?test=1

```
    location / {
            alias /root/phone_build/;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args =404;
    }
    location /web_build {
            alias /root/web_build/;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args =404;
    }

    #location / {
    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_send_timeout 300s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

I tried with ?$query_string but still doesn't work. Any recommendations? Thank your

Comment: Obviously query parameters will be silently and unconditionally ignored by `index.html` (as it is a static file) - they may have meaning only for the API where you're proxy_passing relevant requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Igo, my react app uses query params to work so they don't have to be ignored

Comment: The "index.html" file inside `try_files` directive can not access the query parameters because it is not a runnable code - nginX can't run it. Query parameters will be received by your API which is running at `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) incorrectly. The *file* terms match filenames and do not need the `$is_args$args`, otherwise, when you add a query string to the request, you will simply force a `404` response.

Also, use `root` instead of `alias`. The [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) is only required for special cases.

Try:

```
index index.html;

location / {
        root /root/phone_build;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}
location /web_build {
        root /root;
        try_files $uri /web_build/index.html =404;
}
location /api {
    ...
}
```